# Where is the preffered position to put a simple control loop in a ROS2 Node (C++) for obstacle avoidance

Tags: ros2, callback, laserscan, obstacle-avoidance, logic-control

I am working on a turtlebot simulation with ROS2, and I would like the robot to stop when it hits a wall.

Where is the proper place to implement simple logic (for example, if distance < 10 then stop)? Right now, I have code in the callback, but this isn't ideal especially if the code took a while to run it could cause sensor messages to be missed. Also, if I wanted to only check for obstacles every 2secs, putting a delay in the callback is also not a good idea.

What is the preferred method/where is the preferred place to add this logic, and also how can I delay it so the logic only checks the laser scan every 2 seconds?

````
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/laser_scan.hpp"
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/twist.hpp"

class LaserScanReader : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    LaserScanReader()
        : Node("laser_scan_reader")
    {
        subscription_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>(
            "scan", 10, std::bind(&LaserScanReader::topic_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
        cmd_vel_publisher_ =
            this->create_publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 10);
    }
    void publish_cmd_vel(geometry_msgs::msg::Twist cmd_vel)
    {
        cmd_vel_publisher_->publish(cmd_vel);
    }

private:
    void topic_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr msg) const
    {
        int center_index = msg->ranges.size() / 2;
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Center reading: '%f'", msg->ranges[center_index]);
        if (msg->ranges[center_index] < 10)
        {
            // stop robot here/publish 0 to cmd_vel (is there a better place to do this)
            //  how can I cehck every 2secs (insted of everytime callback runs)
        }
    }
    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>::SharedPtr subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<LaserScanReader>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general computations specific to the node are implemented as member functions. If it gets way to big you should think about using different threads / callback groups or split your tasks up into different nodes or components. Otherwise there is not really a preferred place to put a computation. It really depends on your software design and your requirements.

Executing something every 2s is much simpler, than dealing with functions that take too long and should execute faster.

For your case you could add a timer callback as a member function, where you do your computation:

```
void timer_callback() {
  // do periodic task
}
```

And add a timer that calls the function every 2 seconds when the node is spinning:

```
timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(2000ms, std::bind(&LaserScanReader::timer_callback, this));
```

The message (or just the data) that you need can be stored as a member variable to share it between the `topic_callback` and `timer_callback`. Don't forget to declare the variable in the class.

Also I would suggest to remove the member function `publish_cmd_vel` and store the publisher `cmd_vel_publisher_` as a member variable, because you will have less code and it is clearer for other persons who read it.

**Edit:**
A good example of how to use timer callbacks is the guide on [how to write a simple publisher node (C++)](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html) in the ROS2 doc.

Comment: @p1unge Did the answers clarified your question? If yes, could you mark your preferred answer as correct :)

Comment: Thanks this is a good answer, I like the idea of a simple periodic timer callback.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't overcomplicate it with what you're trying to do. Its extremely lightweight :-)

> this isn't ideal especially if the code took a while to run it could cause sensor messages to be missed

You're not going to miss a callback on a laser scan checking an operation that trivial unless your sensor is publishing at KHz-level speeds or you're running on an STM32 (and even then?). In the callback is fine for the basic thing you're trying to accomplish.

> I wanted to only check for obstacles every 2secs

I'd have the class contain a member of the last time it was checked. As laser scans come in, check what time it is either using `node->now()` or from the message's header `msg.header.stamp` and don't check it unless the duration between checks is high enough.